# Copy of /dev/null has different behaviours depending on location

Tags: bash, unix, permissions, dev-null

I tried mimicking the behaviour of /dev/null in another location, but some strange error occurs. I learned how to generate a special file similar to /dev/null in [-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146633/bash-dev-null-permission-denied).

When in some folder, e.g. home, the following occurs:

```
$ sudo mknod -m 666 null2 c 1 3
$ cat null2
cat: null2: Permission denied
```

On the other hand, when in /dev, no error occurs:

```
$ cd /dev
$ sudo mknod -m 666 null2 c 1 3
$ cat null2
```

I can reproduce the error on another xubuntu machine, but on a third machine the error does not occur. Any clue whats going on there?

Strangely, on any of these machines, permissions and major/minor are identical:

```
$ ls -la null2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Mär  4 17:42 null2
$ ls -la /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Mär  4 11:46 /dev/null
```

Also same when copying /dev/null

```
$ sudo cp -pR /dev/null null2 && cat null2
cat: null2: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please, also show what `id` returns on all the systems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Is the `nodev` mount option set for the file system containing your home directory?

Specifying `nodev` forces the file system to not interpret block special devices (like the `null2` special file you create with `mknod`).

Comment: `mount | grep home`
gives
`dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/home/user/.Private on /home ....` 
I guess that means the mount option is not set, right?

Comment: Hmmmm. Some mount options (e.g. `group`, `owner`,  `user`, `users`) automatically imply `nodev`. What's in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: ah, well. It definitely has something to do with mount options. On my sda6 where /home is located the error occurs. On the drive with mount point / everything runs smoothly.
Maybe we can track down where the problem comes from?
my `/etc/fstab`has the following: `UUID=... / ext4 errors=remount -ro 0 1 UIID=... /home ext4 defaults 0 2 UUID=... none swap sw 0 0`